# PHP Form That Updates Answers

Tags: php

I am currently working in PHP I am new to development in PHP and I am having quite a time trying to get a form to submit then update a value each time it is submitted.

So here is the gist of it. I am submitting my form to self at which time it runs this:

```
<div id="quiz">
    <form method="post" id="test" action="">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php $question->set_results() ?>">
        Answer A<input type="radio" name="answer" value="a">
        Answer B<input type="radio" name="answer" value="b">
        Answer C<input type="radio" name="answer" value="c">
        Answer D<input type="radio" name="answer" value="d">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

class test_results{

    public function get_results(){
        $this->lastanswer = array();
        $this->personsanswer = $_POST['answer'];
        $this->allanswers = array_push($this->lastanswer, $this->personsanswer);
        implode($this->lastanswer);
        echo $this->allanswers;


    }
}
```

After this runs it seems to work but instead of updating the variable it just adds a number where I wanted it to update. All in all I just want to be able to submit a form, after submitting a form I have a hidden field in the form and I want it to update that hidden field with the ALL of the previous options chosen. I have gotten it as far as to update one option at a time but not multiple times.

My end goal is to have a questionnaire form where users fill out answers one question at a time and each time they submit the form the hidden field holds ALL of the previous answer letters in it.

Comment: You are going to need to have somewhere you store the results of your form (like a database) and then retrieve those results and use them in your form page. The way you have this setup will not work as each time the form is submitted re-instantiates it.

Comment: Oh, So it needs to hook into my MySQL database? I thought that it would be able to carry the variable over each time and push a new variable in. I guess I was mistaken. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_results()` is not specified in the question.

You will need to take into account `$_POST["answer"]` inside `set_results`. Also, you will need to post the `hidden` field as well, otherwise you will lose your information. So, first, change your `form` to post the `hidden` field as well:

```
<div id="quiz">
    <form method="post" id="test" action="">
        <input name="answers" type="hidden" value="<?php $question->set_results() ?>">
        Answer A<input type="radio" name="answer" value="a">
        Answer B<input type="radio" name="answer" value="b">
        Answer C<input type="radio" name="answer" value="c">
        Answer D<input type="radio" name="answer" value="d">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

and then you will need to calculate something like

```
$_POST["answers"].($_POST["answers"] ? "," : "").$_POST["answer"]
```

somewhere, so you will get the correct result, returned to the `hidden` field as `value`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was on the same track but I didnt think it would be that simple LOL. I was trying to do it with javascript LMAO. It was working but I had to disable checkboxes after they clicked on the first one as to not append wrong answers to it. This makes my life a lot easier. Thanks

Comment: Oh man, Thanks again, querying the database everytime would have been a disaster. I dont know why I didnt see this in the first place but you are a life saver. THANKS

Comment: @JoeAlvini you are welcome, I am happy the problem has been solved.